# Can I ommit the strict parameter in PHP in_array() when all objects are of the same type?

Tags: php, arrays, types

I use PHP's [in_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function.

The following PHP code example:

```php
<?php

$basket = [ 'apple', 'pear', 'banana' ];

if (!in_array('raspberry', $basket)) {
    $basket[] = 'raspberry';    
}

var_dump($basket);
```

Do you suggest to specify the `strict = true` parameter?

I think it is not necessary because it is ensured that there are only strings in the array (no null, nor something of other type).
Also the 1st argument of the function is ensured to be a string.
Because I am unsure and would like to know if it is correct to specify `strict = true` only for cases when there objects in the array of various types and the argument might be of a different type.

Looking forward to hear more from the community here.

Comment: Well, what happens when you add it or remove it? Is the result different? (In this case it shouldn't be because as you said, everything involved is a string). Whether you should add it depends what you want. Do you want it to do strict type comparisons, or loose type comparisons in the cases where the array items are (potentially) of a different type to the item(s) being compared? Decide, and then act accordingly. We don't know your requirements.

Comment: In my decade of PHP experience, I don't think I've ever done `in_array(..., ..., true)`; when I'm working with single value arrays like this, they are all the same type (strings being a good example), and the search value is also a string. So `strict: true` isn't necessary. The documentation you linked showed when it would be necessary (`in_array(12.4, ['12.4', 12.4], true)`) so yeah, it's going to depend on your use case.

Comment: Compare https://3v4l.org/rq1l5 with  https://3v4l.org/PiPib, for example. You need to decide what result you want in cases such as this, and then set the option according to your needs. We can't tell you what to do, it's your decision.

Comment: @ADyson: I'm totally with you, however in the code example it is specified per the default value `false`. Which can also lead to a different answer: Do you want the code to communicate the parameter more clearly? Strictly speaking, yes, you want that (if you don't immediately throw it away) as even while it is `false`, when you leave that parameter out, the original intend was not written down. Martin is aware of that parameter, but if we would not know this question of him and were reading the code later, we would need to ask him first for clarification. Better then have the code speaking.

Comment: Thanks folks for your replies. 
From what I understand now, I should write the `strict: false` explicitly to be clear about my intention: "not relying on strict comparison but on weak comparison". Right?

Comment: If that is the behaviour you want, then that is something you can do to make the code a bit clearer, yes. But it is the default option anyway.

Comment: I'm again with what @ADyson commented already: Your option. The code itself does not dictate it, therefore it can only be a stylistic improvement at most, but never a requirement. Why not play with it and find your style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you suggest to specify the strict = true parameter? [of in_array()]

For the case you outline in the question, no, but only because I would not even suggest to use `in_array()` there at all (and the `if` etc.), but just:

```php
$basket = ['apple', 'pear', 'banana', 'raspberry'];
```

But not without confirming your writing with a *"strictly speaking, yes"*:

> [Is it] correct to specify strict = true only for cases when there [are] objects in the array of various types and the argument might be of a different type [?]

Yes, this is correct, especially when all values have the same type and there is no difference between weak (`==`) and strict (`===`) comparison for that type (hint: this can differ per type, e.g. object, array and it is true in your example with the string type).

```php
if (!in_array('raspberry', $basket)) {
    $basket[] = 'raspberry';    
}
```

Therefore, the rule of thumb is to specify it as `true` like always, when you *want* or *mean* strict comparison. This is so that your code communicates better. And vice-versa for `false`.

In your example, you won't need to verify the types of the first parameters to find out whether or not strict comparison is in effect, for example, if you would have used $strict = true. You just see it, because it is written in the third parameter.

```php
if (!in_array('raspberry', $basket, true)) {
    $basket[] = 'raspberry';    
}
```

```php
if (!in_array('raspberry', $basket, false)) {
    $basket[] = 'raspberry';    
}
```

When not specifying it and revisiting the code later, it is not clear any longer what was intended by the original author. So it makes the code easier to maintain when you specify the third parameter, regardless of true or false.

https://php.net/in_array

Comment: I understand your explanations like that. I should write `false` explicitly to make sure others understand that I want to rely on weak comparison.

Comment: Yes, that's the takeaway. And honestly, at least for myself: Be it two days or two weeks already, it helps me to pick up at such places directly seeing it. If you're using PhpStorm as IDE, you will notice that the `false` is a bit "in the shadows", so you even see immediately in the editor that this is the default value. We know that strictly speaking we don't need it there (for the code to work), but still it expresses our intention. It helps me for development, maintaining, bug-fixing and refactoring as well as code review, even _rubberducking_. Use it as a tool, YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

You are mostly correct in your logic about the `strict` parameters. For one, I rarely use it because I rarely deal with mixed arrays in my actual codebase and when I have to deal with mixed array, I prefer to convert them to a particular type before doing comparison.

As per the documentation of `in_array` on [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php), here is the definition of the `strict` parameter:

> strict
>
> If the third parameter strict is set to true then the in_array() function will also check the types of the needle in the haystack.
>
> Note:
>
> Prior to PHP 8.0.0, a string needle will match an array value of 0 in non-strict mode, and vice versa. That may lead to undesirable results. Similar edge cases exist for other types, as well. If not absolutely certain of the types of values involved, always use the strict flag to avoid unexpected behavior.

According to this definition and your use case, you do not need to pass `strict=true` for the comparison to work correctly.